# No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'setTitle:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield

I'm working on a Quiz app where I load the questions form a text file.

I have a working verison of the app for OS X however now I'm recreating it for iOS and I run in to a few problems I'm not sure about.

This is the code that will load the questions to the interface of the app:

```
- (void)loadQuestionsAndAnswersIntoInterface {

    NSDictionary *QADictionary = [questionsAndAnswers objectAtIndex:currentQuestion];

    [question setStringValue:[QADictionary valueForKey:@"question"]];
    [answer1 setTitle:[[QADictionary valueForKey:@"answers"] objectAtIndex:0]];
    [answer2 setTitle:[[QADictionary valueForKey:@"answers"] objectAtIndex:1]];
    [answer3 setTitle:[[QADictionary valueForKey:@"answers"] objectAtIndex:2]];

    //[question setValue:[QADictionary valueForKey:@"question"]];
}
```

This code works fine on the OS X app when the answers are NSButtons and the question is a NSTextfield.

However now when those are changed tu UIButtons and a UITextField I get these errors:

```
1. No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'setTitle:'
2. No visible @interface for 'UITextField' declares the selector 'setStringValue:'
```

So I'm assuming this has to do with it being UIButtons etc. However I'm not sure how I would load the questions any other way.

Comment: BTW - You should be using `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:` in your dictionary references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states `UIButton` don't have any `setTitle:` instance method, it only have [setTitle:forState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:)

Same like `UITextField` don't have any `setStringValue:` instance method, for setting text you can use the [setText:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/text) method.

Change your code to:

```
[question setText:[QADictionary valueForKey:@"question"]];
[answer1 setTitle:[[QADictionary valueForKey:@"answers"] objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[answer2 setTitle:[[QADictionary valueForKey:@"answers"] objectAtIndex:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[answer3 setTitle:[[QADictionary valueForKey:@"answers"] objectAtIndex:2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```